# Courant & Robbins Intuitive Demonstration of the Non Denumerability of the Real Number Line

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Courant & Robbins [What is Mathematics](https://archive.org/details/WhatIsMathematics/page/n105/mode/2up?q=real), on pages 82 & 83 a measure based intuitive proof that the real number line is non denumerable is made :

1. Assume the real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ can be listed as $a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n,...$
2. Associate with each n a line interval of length $1 / 10^n$
3. Add up the line lengths around each real number $a_n$ :

$$ 1/10^1 + 1/10^2 + 1/10^3 + ... = 1/9$$

4. Since the length of the interval $[0,1]$ is $1$ we have a contradiction as $1/9\ne 1$.
5. Hence the real numbers can't be mapped to the natural numbers.
6. A note is added to say that if $\epsilon \cdot 1 / 10^n$ was used instead then that shows the measure (length) of a denumerable set of points would have to be zero (and not the $1/9$ that would apply to a countable set of intervals).
7. The book indicates that this provides a intuitive proof that the real number line can't be mapped to the natural numbers, but needs a "fuller analysis" to make a watertight proof.

**So the question is :  What is the precise mathematical reason why it isn't a full mathematical demonstration that the real numbers are uncountable - i.e. where are the 'gaps' that the "fuller analysis" would need to address?**

Comment: Instead of the real numbers, start with an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$. At first sight, the proof appears to go through unchanged, which would demonstrate that the rationals are not denumerable. Where does the proof fall down? This is not, I would say, obvious -- what do _you_ think?

Comment: Do you mean "enumerable" ?

Comment: @Peter: [no](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-among-enumerable-denumerable-and-countable-sets).

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the main gap is that the argument uses something like the following implicitly, without proof:

> Lemma: Suppose that we have intervals $[a_i, b_i]$ for $i \in \mathbb N$, and that $[a, b] \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} [a_i, b_i]$. Then $b - a \leq \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} b_i - a_i$.

This is *true*, and that makes intuitive sense, but it is not obvious. Other weird things happen with infinity, so why should the size of intervals carry over so nicely?

Comment: So I guess the question is why the [limit of the sum of $1/2^n$ terms] isn't the usual geometric sum of 1/9 when line lengths are being considered. What happens to stop the 'obvious' formula applying ? Is there something going on that makes the line lengths bigger than they appear ? Or is the sum $\sum_{i \in \mathbb N} b_i - a_i$ in your formula not the usual sum ?

Comment: @Confusdius, no, the lengths do in fact sum in the way that you would expect -- the lemma above is true! -- but you do have to _prove_ the lemma. (If you haven't, I can recommend trying, and you'll find that it's not totally trivial.)

Comment: The lemma is true if $[a, b]$ is understood to mean $\{x\in \Bbb R\mid a\le x \le b\}$, but it's false if $[a, b]$ is understood to mean $\{x\in \Bbb Q\mid a\le x \le b\}$, so there is definitely more going on than meets the eye.  C&R's claim that this is a proof is looking worse and worse.

Comment: @MeesdeVries : OK thanks - I am looking up the proof to see why the Lemma is true for R but not true for Q.

Comment: @Confusdius, I don't know if you'll find this exact lemma in this exact form printed anywhere, although a proof of something similar to this _should_ be in every textbook on measure theory. The crucial fact you want to use is that $[a, b]$ is compact. (That crucial fact fails, of course, for intervals of rational numbers, which is why the proof indeed does not go through for $\mathbb Q$.)

Answer (score 0):

The notion of length of a set such as an infinite union of intervals needs to be made precise in terms of this or that measure, say the Lebesgue measure.  Notice that the argument uses $\sigma$-additivity (countable additivity) of the Lebesgue measure, since one expects the measure of the intervals $[a_n,a_n+\tfrac1{10^n}]$ to be at most the sum of the measures of the individual intervals.

Thus there are two technical problems with this argument:

1. Developing a suitable measure to make sense of the calculation;
2. Proving that the measure is $\sigma$-additive.

Now the big surprise: one cannot prove in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory that the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-additive.  Namely, one needs the Axiom of Countable Choice to be able to prove that.

Therefore in the end this seemingly "elementary" proof turns out to be quite non-elementary.